# Closed form of $\arccos\left(\frac{2 \pi}{2^N}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry

Is there a closed form for $\arccos\left(\dfrac{2 \pi}{2^N}\right)$ in terms of $N \in \mathbb{Z}, N \ge 3$?

I'm not super optimistic, but I'm not sure how to really start exploring the problem, either.

Comment: Why would you want to find an inverse trig function of a rational multiple of $\pi$.  Usually a rational multiple of $\pi$ is the output of an inverse trig function, not an input.

Comment: It has to do with a sinusoid evaluated at Chebyshev points.

Answer (score 1):

$$\arccos z= \frac {\pi} {2} - \left( z + \left( \frac {1} {2} \right) \frac {z^3} {3} + \left( \frac {1 \cdot 3} {2 \cdot 4} \right) \frac {z^5} {5} + \cdots\ \right) 
= $$
$$=\frac {\pi} {2} - \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {\binom{2n} n z^{2n+1}} {4^n (2n+1)}; \qquad | z | \le 1 $$

Comment: Okay, but can you pull the $2^N$ term out from the infinite series?  As it is, it's a bit of a tautology, isn't it?

Comment: @Adi -- where did this series come from?  I considered that the Taylor's series is a "closed form", but as per Jay above, it is kind of a tautology.

Answer (score 0):

These are kind of trivial, but maybe they are closed enough for you:

$$\arccos(z) = i \cdot \log\left(z - i\sqrt{1-z^2}\right)$$

or

$$\arccos(z) = \int_z^1 \dfrac{dz}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}$$